# Building a Simple Server using Open62541 in a debug environment

Tags: c, c++11, visual-c++, open62541

I built a server using open62541 architecture by referring to the documentation provided at this
[page](https://open62541.org/doc/current/tutorial_server_firststeps.html).
The following input to the command prompt `gcc -std=c99 open62541.c myServer.c -lws2_32 -o myServer.exe` generates the executable. The architecture is compatible only with std c99 library and reference to the Winsock library `-lws2_32` must be added in the command , otherwise, it won't generate the executable and linker errors are produced.
[image: Folder structure]

I am successful at generating the executables using command prompt ,now I want to do the same( generate the server program executable) using the applications "Visual Studio" / "Codeblocks" as I want to debug the program.

How to provide inputs to the compiler of Visual Studio/Codeblocks to include std c99 and Winsock libraries explicitly ? Is anyone successful in migrating the open62541 to debug environements ?

Comment: Please search for the errors befor asking another question. None of this is new.

Comment: Hi , the question is not about the error actually, i want to know how to input the command line argument to visual studio